# Open a terminal with a login prompt

Tags: linux, terminal, login

I want to open a terminal (xterm, gnome-terminal, tilda, whatever) and have it prompt for a username and password to login as.  I thought this would be simple but all my Google results are polluted with stuff about making bash a login shell, which means something completely different as running `bash --login` produces does not ask for a username and password.

Surely there is a way to do this?

**EDIT:** The environment is an embedded device.  I want to have a way for technicians to be able to open a terminal overtop of the WebUI/browser, login and fix stuff.

**ANSWER:** `xterm -e login`

OR (more dangerously) something along the lines of:

```
#!/bin/bash
while :; do
  read -p "User: " USER
  su - $USER -c "bash";
done;
```

Comment: Login to... what?

Comment: Login to a shell.

Comment: You *are* logged in already... This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem): what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Or if you want to login in as another user, use `su` (as an example: `su - anotheruser`)

Comment: Yes but I wish to have a terminal open but no access to shell until someone logs in.

Comment: Perhaps [my answer on askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/a/594872/295286) may be helpful ? Simple solution, uses gnome-terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could try this:

> Open ***Terminal Preferences*** -> *Profiles* -> Select the profile
>   *click edit* -> In "**Title and Command**" Tab, enable "**Run a custom command instead of my shell**" and in "**custom command**" text box
>   enter **su - `<login user`>**

Apply the settings and open a new terminal window to see if it works as desired.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interacting with an x window server (gui), then by this point you have already logged in. There is no reason to prompt for what user to become since you are already authenticated.

Your options are:

- Log out and log in as a different user
- Use `su foo` to change to a different user

Perhaps what you are really looking for are virtual consoles.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + x ( where x = any one of the function keys, F1, F2, ect..)

( Use  <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> +  <kbd>F7</kbd>   to return back to your original x window )

You will then be prompted which user to log in as.